# sql group by date giving wrong results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I didn't really knew how to name a topic, so forgive me pls :c
I want to get some statistics from database. I have 3 tables, something like this:

```
Sent messages: 
id(send_id)
stamp(timestmap)

Replies:
id
send_id
stamp(timestamp)

Opened:
id
send_id
stamp
```

The problem is that in Opened table I am saving stamp of every user mail open. So if user open our email 3 times, there is 3 mails:

```
id      [1, 2, 3]                                        
send_id [1, 1, 1]                      
stamp   [2017-08-06 15:15:12, 2017-08-07 12:11:12, 2017-08-08 20:15:05]
```

And now, I want to have statistics for each day, should looks like this:

```
sent  opened replied date
50    35     10      2017-08-01
20    15     5       2017-08-02
125   80     20      2017-08-03
```

And here is my question, is this possible to check if specific send_id already exist in previous row, and skip counting, because now, if user open email in 3 different day I have +1 in every one of that day, but it should add 1 only at first day that he opens it.

My current select:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) as "sent",
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN o.send_id is NULL THEN NULL ELSE s.id END) as "opened",
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.send_id is NULL THEN NULL ELSE s.id END) as "replied",      
       o.stamp::timestamp::date as date
from db_send s
left join db_reply r ON(r.send_id = s.id)
left join db_send_open o ON (o.send_id = s.id)

group by date
order by date
```

So the problem is: I have much bigger number of opened mails, because I don't know how to group them only by send_id(not by date, but I have to group by date too :ccc, so conflict of interests) and pick one with lowest date

Comment: Simply `group by o.stamp::timestamp::date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query which can solve your problem. It's almost same as what Vao has provided. But that CTE usually occupies a memory space in the database during the runtime as CTE can be used multiple time in the query script. It's advisable to use CTE only when the same result set is reused. Since this is a mail system, I assume the records you deal with is very high, hence having CTE may put down your performance.

Also I have assumed to have senttime as opendate if a mail is never opened. If not needed, you can just remove the case statement.

```
select case when b.opendate is null then date(a.senttime) else b.opendate 
end opendate,count(a.id) mail_sent,count(b.send_id) "read",count(distinct 
c.send_id) replied
from waggle.sent_kn a
left join 
(select send_id,date(min(opentime)) opendate  from
waggle.opened_kn
group by send_id)b
on a.id=b.send_id
left join waggle.replied_kn c
on c.send_id = a.id
group by case when b.opendate is null then date(a.senttime) else b.opendate 
end;
```

Hope this helps!! :)

Comment: Thanks :o Much better performance!! I also change count(a.id) to count(case when a.sent != b.opendate then null else a.id end) mail_sent, because at date where only where opens it was still counting sends.  Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

you can preaggreagte open data in CTE, smth like:

```
with db_send_open as (
select min(stamp) stamp, send_id
from db_send_open
group by send_id
)
select COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) as "sent",
       count (o.send_id) as "opened",
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN r.send_id is NULL THEN NULL ELSE s.id END) as "replied",      
       o.stamp::timestamp::date as date
from db_send s
left join db_reply r ON(r.send_id = s.id)
left join db_send_open o ON (o.send_id = s.id)

group by date
order by date
```

Comment: Its just narrowed dates, but opens are still counted wrong :c but thanks for thi WITH clause , never heard of it, I will read about it :)

Comment: @kamilke Its hard to tell without data sample, but with preaggregation in CTE, you should just `count (o.send_id) as "opened"` to get the right count

Comment: May some powerful forces bless your children and family. Its almost working, i just need some final adjustments. Thank you! <3